# Deprecated Header warning (C++)

Tags: c++, header, deprecated

I keep receiving the deprecated header warning:

```
#ifdef __DEPRECATED
#warning This file includes at least one deprecated or antiquated header. \
Please consider using one of the 32 headers found in section 17.4.1.2 of the \
C++ standard. Examples include substituting the <X> header for the <X.h> \
header for C++ includes, or <iostream> instead of the deprecated header \
<iostream.h>. To disable this warning use -Wno-deprecated.
#endif
```

However, I don't see any deprecated header called by my project (including the headers called by my libraries). These are the header I am loading (or, at least the ones that I am seeing): `iostream` `math.h` `assert.h` `fstream` `vector` `time.h`.

In section 17.4.1.2 http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1905.pdf there is only a list of the header one *should* use.

1) Is there somewhere a list of the deprecated ones?

2) Any idea on how to get out of the preprocessor which one is the exact header he doesn't like?

CHEERS!

Comment: Why are you using <math.h> instead of <cmath> ?

Comment: @Nicol I am using gcc 4.2.1 LLVM

Comment: @Paul R, no reason for that :) It was simply the one I remembered..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The headers coming from the C world are to be prefixed with `c`, and not postfixed.
That means you'll want to include `cmath`, `cassert` and `ctime`.

In those cases, only the header name is subject to deprecation, not the contents.

*Note*: you can deduce which headers are subject to this kind of deprecation by matching their names in the document you link to.

Obviously, this only works for standard headers. For instance, `unistd.h` will always be `unistd.h`.

Comment: Thanks @RaphaelSP . I substituted the headers you refer to. However, I keep getting the warning. What do you mean by "matching their names in the document you link to"? Do you mean simply "searching for those names"?

Comment: @Enzo: okay, my sentence is pretty convoluted for what it means :) so yes, look up your headers; either they do not appear in the list at 17.4.1.2 - and then they`re not standard, or they do in a slightly different form (e.g. wihout `.h` or with a `c`), and then you should use the form mentioned in the standard because yours is depcrecated indeed.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know GCC enough that I can tell whether there is a way to know precisely which headers are deprecated.

Comment: However, you could use `-M` to list all included headers, and see if you missed one of them.